# How to allocate space for the head of linked list in C?

Tags: c, linked-list, valgrind

```
    struct node {
        int data;
        struct node *next;
    };

    int main() {

        struct node *head = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        struct node *current = head;
        ...
    };
```

Though this piece of code can run without any warning or error, Valgrind will give some messages saying `Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)`, `Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation`

I can't figure out what's going wrong. We defined a `node` struct outside the `main` function. So I think we can use `sizeof(struct node)`, isn't it?

Comment: Usually the head of a linked list is just a pointer, not a `struct` and so it doesn't require any memory allocation. Its value will be `NULL` (empty list) or a valid pointer to the first node.

Comment: @WeatherVane's comment about the head of the list is correct, but every node allocation for the list using the above method will generate the same complaint from Valgrind, so there is a good question here.

Comment: @WeatherVane I modified it as `struct node *head`; then `struct node *current  = malloc(sizeof(struct node));` then it comes up with `segamentation falut(core dumped)`.

Comment: 1) malloc returns `void*`, you need to cast it to `(node*)`
2) malloc does not initialize memory, so you need to do it. `memset(head, 0, sizeof(struct node);`

Comment: @Hedgehog in C you don't *need* to cast it. Please see [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: @Hedgehog Generally if you are going to bulk initialize dynamically allocated memory you should consider using `calloc` instead of `malloc`.

Comment: regarding `};` at the end of `main()`  There should be no semicolon  the semicolon causes a compile warning: '11:6: warning: ISO C does not allow extra ‘;’ outside of a function [-Wpedantic]"

Comment: the posted code causes the compiler warning: "8:29: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘malloc’

Comment: The posted code results in a memory leak because the allocated heap memory is never released via a call to `free()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to intialize the data and next pointer with head. I mean

```
head->data = 0;
head->next = NULL;
```

It will pass Valgrind check

Comment: Or use `calloc`.